# Docker pause database let the statement hanging forever

Tags: java, postgresql, docker, jdbc

I have a PostgreSQL database running on docker and I want to test the ability of my java system to handle connection issues with it. I test my java service under 2 different scenarios: by stopping the container (`docker stop postgresContainer`) and by pausing it(`docker pause postgresContainer`)

When I stop the container, JDBC promptly throws an exception which I can catch and handle it, but when I pause, the service get in a locked state which the JDBC statement hangs on executing forever, until the container is "unpaused", when the method flow returns and the pending statements are executed.

Something I also noticed is that when I get the JDBC connection status by calling `connection.isValid(1);` it hangs forever here too.

```java
public void executeStatement(String query) {
    try {
            Connection connection = getConnection();
            Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
            // It gets stuck here forever when the container is "paused"
            // When I unpause, the query to be executed is persisted in DB
            statement.execute(query);

            statement.close();
            connection.close();
    }
        catch (Exception e) {
            statement.close();
            connection.close();
        }
```

Comment: Have you specified the `socketTimeout` connection property? If not, it will wait indefinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my specific case I could solve it by adding both a connection timeout and a connection acquisition timeout.

To set the network timeout I called `connection.setNetworkTimeout(null, timeoutInSeconds * 1000);`. I wasn't able to use it because my postgres driver version was too old

To set a connection acquisition timeout (I'm using c3p0 to handle connection pool), I added the following call when creating the ComboPooledDataSource instance `c3p0ConnectionPool.setCheckoutTimeout(checkoutTimeout);`

Answer (score 1):

See https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/connect.html

Especially :

> connectTimeout = int
>
> The timeout value used for socket connect operations. If connecting to
>   the server takes longer than this value, the connection is broken. The
>   timeout is specified in seconds and a value of zero means that it is
>   disabled.
>
> socketTimeout = int
>
> The timeout value used for socket read operations. If reading from the
>   server takes longer than this value, the connection is closed. This
>   can be used as both a brute force global query timeout and a method of
>   detecting network problems. The timeout is specified in seconds and a
>   value of zero means that it is disabled.